# Plotting in a zooming in matplotlib subplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

This question is from this tutorial found [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/5-powerful-tricks-to-visualize-your-data-with-matplotlib-16bc33747e05):
I want my plot to look like the one below but with time series data and the zoomed data not being `x_lim , y_lim` data but from a different source.
[image]

So in the plot above i would like the intraday data that is from a different source and the plot below would be daily data for some stock. But because they both have different source i cannot use a limit to zoom. For this i will be using yahoo datareader for daily and yfinance for intraday.

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as web
from matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch

df = web.DataReader('goog', 'yahoo')
df.Close = pd.to_numeric(df['Close'], errors='coerce')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 5))
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0., left = 0, top = 1., right = 1)
sub1 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
sub1 = df.Close.plot()

sub2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2) # two rows, two columns, second cell
df.Close.pct_change().plot(ax =sub2)
sub2.plot(theta, y, color = 'orange')
con1 = ConnectionPatch(xyA=(df[1:2].index, df[2:3].Close), coordsA=sub1.transData, 
                       xyB=(df[4:5].index, df[5:6].Close), coordsB=sub2.transData, color = 'green')
fig.add_artist(con1)
```

I am having trouble with xy coordinates. With the code above i am getting :

> TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64')
> according to the rule 'safe'

```
xyA=(df[1:2].index, df[2:3].Close)
```

What i had done here is that my xvalue is the date `df[1:2].index` and my y value is the price `df[2:3].Close`

[image]

Is converting the df to an array and then ploting my only option here? If there is any other way to get the `ConnectionPatch` to work kindly please advise.

---

```
df.dtypes

High         float64
Low          float64
Open         float64
Close        float64
Volume         int64
Adj Close    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Did you solve the issue with the answers you already have? The graph at the bottom says to use a candlestick graph, but if you actually draw a graph, the candles are too small to have any visualization effect because the data spans five years. So, the time series of the monthly candlestick and daily zoom graphs are ambiguous. What are your thoughts on this? I am preparing an answer.

Comment: @r-beginners The plot should show a daily plot in the main graph(purple). This would be to show the detailed long term chart(probebly 12 months). A small segment of  would then be zoomed with an daily chart in smaller time frame say 2 months in one of the two subplot above(green plot). The other one would have a intraday plot of the latest candle(orange). I hope i have answered it. Thanks

Comment: @Slartibartfast All the tools to do that are in my answer. I pasted it together with the code from your question, see the edit on my answer.

Comment: Unless I missed something of course :)

Comment: Do I need to fill in the relevant time period on a line graph where the top left is about 2 months and the top right is the latest candle and the city graph is about 1 year? I see that the answers you already have have been updated in response to your comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way matplotlib dates are plotted are by converting dates to floats as a number of days, starting with 0 on 1970-1-1, i.e. the POSIX timestamp zero. It’s different from that timestamp as it’s not the same resolution, i.e. “1” is a day instead of a second.

There’s 3 ways to compute that number,

- either use `matplotlib.dates.date2num`
- or use `.toordinal()` which gives you the right resolution and remove the offset corresponding to 1970-1-1,
- or get the POSIX timestamp and divide by the number of seconds in a day:

```
df['Close'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Close'], errors='coerce')
df['Change'] = df['Close'].pct_change()

con1 = ConnectionPatch(xyA=(df.index[0].toordinal() - pd.Timestamp(0).toordinal(), df['Close'].iloc[0]), coordsA=sub1.transData,
                       xyB=(df.index[1].toordinal() - pd.Timestamp(0).toordinal(), df['Change'].iloc[1]), coordsB=sub2.transData, color='green')
fig.add_artist(con1)

con2 = ConnectionPatch(xyA=(df.index[-1].timestamp() / 86_400, df['Close'].iloc[-1]), coordsA=sub1.transData,
                       xyB=(df.index[-1].timestamp() / 86_400, df['Change'].iloc[-1]), coordsB=sub2.transData, color='green')
fig.add_artist(con2)
```

You also need to make sure that you’re using values that are in range for the targeted axes, in your example you use `Close` values on sub2 which contains `pct_change`’d values.

Of course if you want the bottom of the boxes as in your example it’s easier to express the coordinates using the axes transform instead of the data transform:

```
from matplotlib.dates import date2num

con1 = ConnectionPatch(xyA=(0, 0), coordsA=sub1.transAxes,
                       xyB=(date2num(df.index[1]), df['Change'].iloc[1]), coordsB=sub2.transData, color='green')
fig.add_artist(con1)

con2 = ConnectionPatch(xyA=(1, 0), coordsA=sub1.transAxes,
                       xyB=(date2num(df.index[-1]), df['Change'].iloc[-1]), coordsB=sub2.transData, color='green')
fig.add_artist(con2)
```

To plot your candlesticks, I’d recommend using the [*mplfinance*](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance) (previously matplotlib.finance) package:

```
import mplfinance as mpf
sub3 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 2)
mpf.plot(df.iloc[30:70], type='candle', ax=sub3)
```

---

Putting all this together in a single script, it could look like this:

```
import pandas as pd, mplfinance as mpf, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas_datareader import data as web
from matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch
from matplotlib.dates import date2num, ConciseDateFormatter, AutoDateLocator
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter

# Get / compute data
df = web.DataReader('goog', 'yahoo')
df['Close'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Close'], errors='coerce')
df['Change'] = df['Close'].pct_change()

# Pick zoom range
zoom_start = df.index[30]
zoom_end = df.index[30 + 8 * 5] # 8 weeks ~ 2 months

# Create figures / axes
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 12))
top_left = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)
top_right = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 2)
bottom = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=.35)

# Plot all 3 data
df['Close'].plot(ax=bottom, linewidth=1, rot=0, title='Daily closing value', color='purple')
bottom.set_ylim(0)

df.loc[zoom_start:zoom_end, 'Change'].plot(ax=top_left, linewidth=1, rot=0, title='Daily Change, zoomed')
top_left.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter())

# Here instead of df.loc[...] use your intra-day data
mpf.plot(df.loc[zoom_start:zoom_end], type='candle', ax=top_right, xrotation=0, show_nontrading=True)
top_right.set_title('Last day OHLC')

# Put ConciseDateFormatters on all x-axes for fancy date display
for ax in fig.axes:
    locator = AutoDateLocator()
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ConciseDateFormatter(locator))

# Add the connection patches
fig.add_artist(ConnectionPatch(
    xyA=(0, 0), coordsA=top_left.transAxes,
    xyB=(date2num(zoom_start), df.loc[zoom_start, 'Close']), coordsB=bottom.transData,
    color='green'
))

fig.add_artist(ConnectionPatch(
    xyA=(1, 0), coordsA=top_left.transAxes,
    xyB=(date2num(zoom_end), df.loc[zoom_end, 'Close']), coordsB=bottom.transData,
    color='green'
))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The 'putting it all together' script is missing imports and maybe other pieces.  Hard to follow to put it all together.

Comment: @merit_2 it’s not using any other imports than from the question and the `mplfinance` I mentioned. But I can add them, sure.